# Using a Matrix of integer values to determine the length of strings in a matrix of strings

Tags: r, matrix, operations

I am trying to create a matrix of character strings of varying length.

So far, I haven't been able to access the elements in the matrix properly in order apply them to a new one.

```
ranNumsVec <- runif(1000, min = 100, max = 1000)

ranNumsVec <- round(ranNumsVec, digits = 0)


clusterSeqLengths <- matrix(data = ranNumsVec, nrow = 10, ncol = 100, 
                            byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)

clusterSeqs <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 100, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)
```

^ These are fine

---

With these functions, I am trying to apply characters with certain probabilities to a separate matrix. (a matrix of strings), such that each string within the matrix is determined by one of the random numbers stored in the random `Nums Vec` above. In the end, I am looking to create a matrix of 1000 sequences of ATGC's of length 100 to 1000 as indicated above.

```
lengthSmallString <- function(clusterSeqLengths)
                    clusterSeqs <- paste(sample("A", "C", "G", "T"),               c                   clusterSeqLengths,replace=TRUE ,prob=c(0.2, 0.55, 0.1,                .                   .15))

fillCharsToLength <- function(clusterSeqs)

                    clusterSeqs <- apply(clusterSeqs, 2, lengthSmallString, simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES 
                    = FALSE)
```

I am not entirely sure how to properly iterate through the matrix and apply the paste function to a string of a certain length. I tried a for loop, but it didn't get me very far

```
for(i=1:nume1(array) in clusterVectorNums)
{
  for(j in clusterVectorNums)
  {
    seqLength <- ranNumsVec[i,j]
    clusterSeqs[i,j] <- paste(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"),
    seqLength, replace=TRUE ,prob=c(0.2, 0.55, 0.1, 0.15)),
    collapse="")
  }
}
```

Comment: The function definitions in the 2nd code snippet look rather strange to me, so I didn't try to edit. Please, double check and correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, if you have a 5 in `clusterSeqLengths[1,1]` you are expecting a sequence of randomly sampled values `c("A","C","G","T")` of length 5 as a single string in your final output `clusterSeqs[1,1]` and you would like to repeat this process for every cell in `clusterSeqLengths`. On the assumption this is the case you could do this using `apply`.

I have modified your presented example such that the numbers and size of the problem are smaller to show results in my post.

```
set.seed(1) # initiliase RNG seed for reproducible results

ranNumsVec <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 5)
ranNumsVec <- round(ranNumsVec, digits = 0)
clusterSeqLengths <- matrix(data = ranNumsVec, nrow = 5, ncol = 2, 
                            byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)

# first make a function which takes an n for
# how long the sequence should be and returns the 
# relevant sequence
f = function(n){
  paste(
    sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"),
           n, replace=TRUE ,prob=c(0.2, 0.55, 0.1, 0.15)
    ),
    collapse="")
}

clusterSeqLengths

##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2    5
## [3,]    3    3
## [4,]    5    3
## [5,]    1    0

# check it works on one value
f(clusterSeqLengths[1,1])
## [1] "C"
```

Then use `apply` with `index = c(1,2)` to apply the function `f` to each cell

```
(clusterSeq = apply(clusterSeqLengths,c(1,2),f))
##      [,1]    [,2]   
## [1,] "C"     "CCCC" 
## [2,] "AC"    "CTCCA"
## [3,] "TCA"   "CCT"  
## [4,] "GCTGC" "ATC"  
## [5,] "A"     ""
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: @MakennaSophiaHerl no problem. If the answer solves your problem, you should consider upvoting or accepting this answer such that future readers can also benefit